# scala akka - Number of threads grows indefinitly even when actors are killed

Tags: scala, akka, actor, executioncontext

I'm creating an actor per unit of work. Each actor creates a thread pool.
when the work is completed it messages its sender which will inturn send the child actor a poison pill

I noticed that the number of threads in the jvm process is still growing indefinitly even though the child actors are "killed"

Example

```
class ParentActor (...) extends Actor {
 ....
 ....

 val childActor = props(...child actor props...)
 val resultFuture = childActor ? "do some work"
 ...
 resultFuture onComplete {
   ...
   childActor ! PoisonPill // "kill" the child actor
 }

class ChildActor(...) extends Actor {
  val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
...

  receive {
    ...
    sender ! "done"
  }

  override def postStop() {
    println("post stop called") // the actor prints this
  }
}
```

Shouldn't the actor be GCd along with its threads?

Comment: You need to shut down these thread pools. I am not sure if it is even possible for GC to clean those up. Threads form the root of the GC liveness check after all.

Comment: Also, it is a bit weird to have actors create thread pools. Wouldn't you want Akka to manage those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread pools don't get automatically garbage collected. See the docs for the Java `ThreadPoolExecutor`

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

> A pool that is no longer referenced in a program AND has no remaining threads may be reclaimed (garbage collected) without being explicitly shutdown.

But since you are creating a fixed pool, it will never have "no remaining threads". So it will never be collected by the JVM, even though the child actor is stopped.

You could implement a cleanup method in a `postStop`, calling `shutdownNow()`. But, as Thilo points out, managing thread pools in child actors is pretty weird. You don't explain why you want to do that, but I'd consider letting Akka manage your threads.